# Recommend database in pure node.js with no dependencies?

Tags: database, deployment, node.js

I would like to know if a pure node.js web app can be developed, which means very simple deployment. From my understanding since node.js is good at i/o, a database in node.js should be good too. Does one exist? Especially one that lives in RAM and occasionally persists to disk.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. Too much re-inventing the wheel. Use an existing database. If you want trivial storage then just write objects to file as JSON.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of I don't see the problem in installing redis or mongodb. It can be done without any effort at all.

That said there are a number of such databases like:

- [ministore](https://github.com/stagas/ministore): save at specified intervals.
- [alfred](https://github.com/pgte/alfred): Reads are fast because indexes into files are kept in memory.
- [nStore](https://github.com/creationix/nstore): Also a index of all documents and their exact location on the disk is stored in in memory for fast reads of any document.
- [jsonds](https://github.com/lfdoherty/jsonds): Jsonds is a 'data store' which is just a JSON object which is written to disk at a set frequency.
- [supermarket](https://github.com/pkrumins/node-supermarket)
- [chaos](https://github.com/stagas/chaos)
- [node-dirty](https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty)
- [node-tiny](https://github.com/chjj/node-tiny)
- [nedb](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb): Embedded pure JS database with MongoDB-compatible API.

Also most of these product are very young and should probably not be used in production yet.

---

You could also code something yourself I assume using [node-sqlite3](https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3) to store data back to disc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a database in Node that exists only in ram you could simply use javascript objects and arrays to contain your data. If you need something more powerful with queries that ressemble SQL, then maybe pure javascript objects would not be the best idea. Also, with this idea you could make it persistant by flushing the data to disk using JSON.stringify at a set interval.

Comment: And how could I make a Client-Server Database from this?

Comment: I thought the web app would have the data inside it. If you're going to build a Node web app that uses another Node server to use as a database, this becomes easily complicated and it's basically reinvinting the wheel. I would suggest handling the data inside the web app and not having different servers. If you need to have a standalone database server (for load balancing for example) then using a real database would be ideal (maybe something like Redis). In the end, that would mean less development time, safer and easier to scale.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#database

Sorry for the short answer guys.

Comment: The link is now dead.